# Having ping 600-650ms, will that make browsing much worse?

Tags: ping, satellite

I am thinking to order satellite internet (10/4Mbps). The problem is that ping time is very high (600-650ms). I am wondering how big problem will be that to me. I don't play games. The first thing that came in my mind what it won't work is google autocomplete because it will take half second for each key and meantime I type all word. I will also need to wait 600ms before website will start loading, right? Any other problems?

Answer (score 1):

I ordered satellite Internet service (20/2) to replace the terrible DSL (2/0.7) we're stuck with in our community. The latency is as you said, 500ms-700ms typically. 
This latency manifests in common use as **much** longer, like 2 full seconds x2 (as the response signal suffers the same latency) and some international sites will take almost 10 seconds to initiate loading upon which it loads quickly. This is due to the many hops largely which of course one does not know how many there are but their latencies add to your circa 600ms latency. In practice it's very annoying and oft times one wonders if you've ever clicked on a link and multiple clicks inevitably follow as there's no indication of initiating activity.

As ancient and poor quality as our 2/0.7 DSL is, in normal use it "feels" faster than the satellite which has speeds literally 10-fold that of the DSL.

Forget using VOIP, Skype, remote desktop, streaming video and gaming as the latency makes using them chaotic and impossible with delays. The streaming limitation is NOT due to latency however but the bandwidth cap and it's deceptively easy to deplete it. With none of the above it's still easy to use 30GB-60GB/month cap up.

Of course the speeds in this case are decent, unlike the DSL and downloads fly 'comparatively' as do uploads.

I have noticed that different satellite providers block different websites, ostensibly to lessen traffic in their networks. But you will find some sites albeit rarely so, will not open unless you use a VPN to circumvent this.

I have owned two different Internet satellites from two different companies using different networks. Both worked flawlessly if the issues above are not troubling. Perhaps others had better experiences but I would never return to satellite Internet unless land line ISPs became unavailable.

BTW there are services of wireless Internet which transmits to a modem-like receiver in your home. These can, if the transmitter is reasonably close to your house (several miles), get you anything from 3mbps to 18mbps with a latency of 'only' 100ms. They tend to be priced similarly to satellite. One I know of requires a $400 deposit which they refund *after* you've tried it and returned it should it not work due to the main transmitter being too far from your home receiver. In short I would use any satellite Internet as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

(most) Websites will also take longer to render (ie longer then 600ms) because the website needs to download the main page and then fetch the dependencies (for example images and css files).  Also, a TCP handshake may take a few packets going back and forward.

Things like Skype will also not work as well, and the latency will be very noticeable if you use things like SSH or a remote desktop application.

Another thing (which may not be a problem for you) is that satellite Internet generally comes with quite small data caps relative to regular broadband - at least wherever I have investigated it.

That said, its probably not as bad as it sounds - I live in New Zealand and thus routinely visit sites located overseas, so most stuff has a latency of 100-250ms.